# postForEntity exception in case of 4** error

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller, resttemplate

I created a generic method to call an external API (post call). Everything is working fine if external rest API returns 2** but, in case of any error an exception is raised.

Isn't is possible to treat this 4** response like a normal answer instead of generate an exception? The problem is that I need to get the error message (response body) and send back to the caller.

This is my code:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> post(String api, Map<String, Object> data) { 

    ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);

    try { 

        StopWatch stopwatch = new StopWatch();
        stopwatch.start();

        log.debug("post(): " + host + "/" + api );

        // Set the headers
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        // Convert the Map to Gson
        Gson gson = new Gson(); 
        String json = gson.toJson(data); 

        // Call the API
        HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(json, headers);
        response = new RestTemplate().postForEntity(host + "/" + api, request, String.class);

        stopwatch.split();
        log.info("All request completed [" + response.getStatusCode() + "] in " + stopwatch.getSplitTime());

        return response;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}
```

The external API, in case of error, returns this:

```
ResponseEntity<Integer> response = new ResponseEntity<Integer>();
[.. business code ..]
res.setResponse(new ResponseEntity<String>(CommonValue.userNotFound, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use RestTemplate#exchange(..) methods that return a ResponseEntity. This will not throw an exception but will parse the answer into the ResponseEntity where you can retrieve the status code etc.

Comment: Actually, this does not fix the issue. Exchange still continue to raise the exception.